# Clickable ListView item needs SQL function new item, how?

Tags: android, sql, database, android-listview

I created a `SQLiteDatabase` where I can see the items with the 'View' Button and clicking on it, I get the whole database into a `ListView`. In this `ListView` I would like the items to be clickable and if I click on them, I want to add a new entry to it with the same name, but another id. My code so far:

```
ListView lv;
ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems));
          ListView lv = getListView();
          lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        hornot info = new hornot(this);
        info.open();

        Cursor c = info.getAllTitles();
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
        do{


            todoItems.add(c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1) + " " + c.getString(2));
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
            if (todoItems.size() > 0)
            {
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(sqview.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems));
            }


            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                      //-/////////////////////////
                    }
                  });

            info.close(); 

        }
```

As you see, I put the database items into an array, then I put them into a `ListView`. With an upgrade button I can add items, so I think I need to do something same here.
In the `dbhelper` the `createEntry` function:

```
public long createEntry(String name, String hotness) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        cv.put(KEY_HOTNESS, hotness);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);        
    }
```

In the `main.java` I convert the `EditTexts` to `Strings` then put the values into the database:

```
    String name = sqlName.getText().toString();
    String hotness = sqlHotness.getText().toString();

    hornot entry = new hornot(dbhelp.this);
    entry.open();
    entry.createEntry(name, hotness);
    entry.close();
```

So what should I write for the `onItemClick` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `onItemClick()` method you have the position parameter that indicates the position(in the adapter) of the list row that was clicked. You could then use `getItemAtPosition` on the `ListView` to get the data from the row:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
     String rowData = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position); //you'll need to make the lv as final
     String[] data = rowData.split(" "); //split the result using the spaces (so you could obtain the name, hotness and the other string you use)
     entry.createEntry(data[0], data[1]);
}
```

I don't know your database structure so I can't recomend you something about unique `id`.

Comment: I get an error: database not open in the row:
info.createEntry(data[0], data[1]);
However it is definietly open, since I only close it after the setonitemclick.

Comment: @JaniBela Add `entry.open();` before that line.
`

Comment: Added:
info.open();  info.createEntry(data[0], data[1]);              info.close(); it is okay now

Comment: @JaniBela Well that is normal because your list doesn't know that you added something to the database and that it should recreate the list. To show the new added items you'll have to the same thing you did in the `onCreate` to populate the list: get a cursor, build an `ArrayList` from that cursor and create a new ArrayAdapter to set to the list.

Comment: Ooops. Testing it and accidentaly noticed it is not that good :( If I click on an item, it creates anoither one. Ok so far. But if I click on that item again, it creates two more, not just one. Then three more... Do you know why is that?

Comment: @JaniBela Clicking on a element will add a new copy, clicking the same row again will create another copy and with the previous one created you'll have two copies (and etc). If you want to just make only one copy of a row then you will have to store the status of that row(can make/can't make a copy) outside the list.

Comment: As you advised I added a new cursor, builded a new arraylist etc, and copied after the createEntry... So it is working exactly as you said. It is a little bit weird for me, but i try to store the status of that row.  Thanks again slukian :)

Comment: Hmm, sorry i misunderstood the problem. So if I click on an item and recreat the list immediately, then as if it was counting the whole database then adds all of the items to the list and then the new one. If I go back to the main activity, and view the database, it is correct. So the immediate refresh is somehow wrong.

Comment: @JaniBela I don't understand the problem you have. Every item of the database that you add will be added at the end because this is just how SQLite works. If you want the copy to be after the item on which you clicked than it's your job to order the list to do this.

Comment: Given the next items: "56 aaa bbb"  "57 ccc ddd"  (primary key,name, hotness). If I click on the "56 aaa bbb", then the next appears:   "56 aaa bbb" "57 ccc ddd"  "56 aaa bbb" "57 ccc ddd"  "58 aaa bbb". If I go back to my previous activity and press my view button, it is now correct:  "56 aaa bbb" "57 ccc ddd"  "58 aaa bbb" . I am not sure why sql creates copies about the whole database before adding the right item.. Of course I added a new cursor, arraylist to show the new added items, so the problem may be there

Comment: Refreshing the intent instantly solved the problem but it is not that nice :) But I think I can solve it somehow else. Next time I will express myself better :)